# FeedBurner cannot find valid feed

Tags: rss, blogger, feedburner

I am trying to setup a Feedburner settings for my blog http://mecoffeyjourney.blogspot.com/. But FeedBurner came out this error *'Received HTTP error: "Not Found" while fetching source feed.'*

I have also tried it on FeedValidator - http://feedvalidator.org/, but receive this error *'It looks like this is a web page, not a feed. I looked for a feed associated with this page, but couldn't find one. Please enter the address of your feed to validate.'*

Is it something wrong with the blog template? How can I get my Feeds URL?

Please advise.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blogger generated sitemaps can be accessed via:

```
http://mecoffeyjourney.blogspot.com/atom.xml

http://mecoffeyjourney.blogspot.com/rss.xml

http://mecoffeyjourney.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?orderby=UPDATED
```

logon to feedburner and create your feed by using the `atom.xml` (or any of the above) link.